# How can I get confidence level value in ms bot framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I want to access the confidence level from luis with the middleware so I can route low confidence level responses to humans instead of the bot.

The value I am looking for is this one (gets logged with emulator):

```
Library("*")recognize() recognized: Hallo(0.8215488)
```

Is this even possible in the middleware or does that happen afterwards?

I tried finding it in the "session" but didn't find it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an IntentDialog from the botbuilder library, you could specify the ***intentThreshold*** property which will set the minimum score needed to trigger the recognition of an intent. Check following link for reference: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.iintentdialogoptions.html#intentthreshold

If the user's input is not recognised by your LUIS models or the score value is below that intentThreshold value, the onDefault method from the IntentDialog will handle it. So, it's in here where you could add your logic to hand over the customer conversation from a bot to a human:

```
let recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(models);
let minimumScore = 0.3;
let intentArgs = {};

intentArgs.recognizers = [recognizer];
intentArgs.intentThreshold = minimumScore;

var intents = new builder.IntentDialog(intentArgs)
.onBegin()
.onDefault(
    // Add logic to handle conversation to human
);

library.dialog('options', intents);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. so it seems like there is not really a solution using middleware so your suggestion is better.

I did it like this now:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3530    
     
Btw whats this IntentDialog?

Comment: An IntentDialog is a type of Dialog that will use the LUIS models that you establish on the recognizers list and will potentially recognize the user's intent.

Comment: Seems like IntentDialog is the older method as the official samples dont use it anymore? There also seems to be a per-dialog solution [using triggerAction](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2028m)

Comment: Well, on that link that you shared before, the IntentDialog was used as well. It's not mandatory to use an IntentDialog if you want to use LUIS, of course. You could use a simple dialog: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/basics-naturalLanguage/app.js  
  
About the TriggerAction, I have never used it but it seems that it will interupt any existing dialog and will clear the stack and place the dialog at the root of the stack. If that's what you need, then go for it.